# What is the meaning of the sentences I have mentioned down below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Yesterday I was watching the soccer game and there was english commentary from Peter Drury on Lionel Messi once Messi scored a goal against Napoli. I couldn't grasp what Peter Drury said fully. So can anyone please help me comprehend what he actually said. The following sentence is what I got from what he said. Can anyone please correct it for me.

> **"He is just a conjurer. A ripper up of reason. A dream machine. A perennial scissor of the day. Just another Lionel Messi gem."**

What is **ripper up of reason** if what I heard is right ?

What is **perennial scissor of the day** if what I heard is right too?

OR

Please correct the parts for me where I didn't hear them right.

Here is the link of the HIGHLIGHTS VIDEO. The part I mentioned starts at 4.51 minutes in the VIDEO.

https://hofoot.uprafa.com/player/html/ycYlrBPrMhPoa?popup=yes&autoplay=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is ripper up of reason if what I heard is right ?

It's someone who rips up reason.

It's intended as a metaphor of some kind. Your guess is as good as mine as to what is the intended literal meaning.

> What is perennial scissor of the day if what I heard is right too?

I heard this as "seizer of the day", meaning one who seizes the day.

"Seize the day" is the conventional English translation of the Latin phrase *carpe diem*, originating with (as I quickly google) the poet Horace.

It is usually interpreted to mean to make the most of a moment or of an opportunity.